# How to sort mysql from pre-defined data

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

| id | product_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 |

and I have a data set :
`[{id:2:weight:8},{id:5,weight:6},{id:4,weight:3}]`

I want to get the products which price < 5 and sort them first by weight asc from the dataset above and then sort them by price desc, so  the result should be:

```
[{
id:4,product_id:4,id:4
},{
id:2,product_id:2,id:2
},{
id:3,product_id:3,id:3
},{
id:1:product_id:1,id:1
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) syntax to get the desired results.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.id, t.product_id, t.price, 
    CASE 
        WHEN t.id=2 THEN 8
        WHEN t.id=5 THEN 6
        WHEN t.id=4 THEN 3
        ELSE 0
    END AS weight
    FROM mytable t
    WHERE t.price < 5
) res ORDER BY res.weight ASC, res.price DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the way to short for each column declared in the sorted list. here is an example:

```
select *
from myDataset
where price < 5
order by price desc, weight asc
```